# How to automatically add `data-cy` or `data-test` to react app?

Tags: reactjs, selenium, cypress

I got a task of writing automated end to end UI tests for existing React application. I want to follow what cypress docs suggestion, use `data-cy` attribute values for selecting elements:

> [image]

But there is no such attribute introduced by dev team in the application. Is there any way to automatically (any library) add `data-cy` or `data-test` attributes to existing react app. Or is there any easy way to do it manually, especially due to React's component architecture?

PS: adding selenium tag too because testing using selenium also involves element selection.

Answer (score -2):

Instead doing it via cypress. Get the code from dev, add your

```
data-cy or data-test
```

by yourself and ask your dev team to approve your changes.

please do not waste time on this.